# Jboss 4.2.3.GA number of threads/requests configuration

Tags: jboss

Needed to know where the number of maximum requests/threads are defined. Call are basically made by clients through Spring Remoting. Jboss app exposes a service to be use with HttpInvokerService.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about the `Connector` configuration in JBoss 4.2.3.GA. You will find the relevant configuration in the file `server/<profile>/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml`, focus on the following code snippet:

```
    <Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
         maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
         emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
         connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

In short, you need adjust `maxThreads` value on your need.

> The maximum number of request processing threads to be created by this Connector, which therefore determines the maximum number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. If not specified, this attribute is set to 200. If an executor is associated with this connector, this attribute is ignored as the connector will execute tasks using the executor rather than an internal thread pool.

See full document in the official document [The HTTP Connector](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html).